# Changing an array into individual variables in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach

OK...so I am really not very good at coding.  And I don't understand the language these manuals are done in...for some reason the given examples don't click and I don't understand how or if they are relevant to what I am trying to do.  So searching for answers isn't helping.

I got far enough on my own to strip out unwanted HTML coding from an array and be left with just the pure values.  But that isn't quite where I want to be.  It's halfway.

Let's say I have an array like this

```
$array = "redgreenbluebrown"
```

(by the way I am not sure if what I actually have is an array with four values...or if it was four values that got run together and are now one value)

So lets say I have this:

```
$type
```

where the value of $type is redgreenbluebrown

What I want to get to now...

Is this

```
$type1 = red
$type2 = green
$type3 = blue
$type4 = brown
```

So that I can then call on the individual elements as needed.  I do NOT need to print them out...I need to assign them as individual values to other areas of the program.

The original array comes from an sql query where several rows of info are fetched.

How can I get all the individual values from more than one row?  And assign each gotten value to it's own unique variable instead of an array?  In my case the array isn't helpful...I need the individual values.

Could anyone please help a novice who is trying very hard...but for whom this stuff just plain does not click, because not of the examples shown ever bear any significance to what I am actually trying to accomplish?

I'm good with basic stuff, but this is not exactly basic.  At least, not to me!!

Not sure If I should be using an "explode" function, an "implode" function, an "extract" function or a "foreach" function...or how to get any of those to do what I am actually wanting.  Sorry if I sound like a terribly clueless newbie.

Comment: what if you have value like `carpet` - how will you split it?

Comment: how would you know where to split `redgreenbluebrown` ? "The original array comes from an sql query where several rows of info are fetched" i think you need to step back and start fixing this at the query. this is what we call an X  Yissue

Comment: You need to back up to the point where you have an array and ask how to get that the way you want it.

Comment: You don't need to say _sorry_ because of the fact that you are new in this field. Each of us was a newbie at some moment ;-) I think, in a long question you are asking something that remains too abstract to us. I would suggest to reedit the question and present to us exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Or post a new question and delete this one.  Post the array from the DB and what you want the end result to look like.  You can include code you tried.

Comment: In principle, from a database table you are fetching an array with items. Each item is an array as well and represents the corresponding - found - table row. The keys represent the column names and the values represent the column values for the row. What you later decide to do with the elements of the whole array is up to you, dependending on what task you have to perform.

Comment: _by the way I am not sure if what I actually have is an array with four values_ its not an array it a scalar value

Comment: OK...so not really certain what a scalar value actually is...and how I break it into it's component parts?  As I said, I am really a bit into a big muddy I have never been into.  

I'm not terribly good at more than the most basic code.  And that is being kind.

Comment: `$array = "redgreenbluebrown"` is not an array, it's a string. PHP arrays are comma separated groups of strings like `$array = array('red','green','blue','brown');`

Comment: OK, it won't let me post another question right now.  I guess I am a horrible stupid newbie that does not know how to ask for what I want.  I could use some help here if there is something I am doing wrong.  I am not looking to make a career out of this, just answer a question about something I want to do in one PHP program...that I have never tried before, and not sure how to proceed.  I am sorry for being so stupid everyone.

Comment: It does not matter anymore now.  I got where I wanted to get to.  Certainly not the "right way" - I gave up trying, the "right way" is just too difficult.  So I did it with several calls of individual lines, setting variables after each call.

Not the "right way" but I just can't seem to grasp it.  I don't learn the same way other people do...which is why I frustrate a lot of people.

Thanks everyone for trying.  I ended up doing it a way I could understand, and which uses probably 6 times as many code lines as a pro could do it in...but it WORKS.  i'm a bit the utilitarian.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to name the variables, you could use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$array = array('red','green','blue','brown');

${$array[0]} = $array[0]; // $red = 'red
${$array[1]} = $array[1]; // $green = 'green'
${$array[2]} = $array[2]; // $blue = 'blue'
${$array[3]} = $array[3]; // $brown = 'brown'
```

Or you could loop through the array:

```
$types = array('red','green','blue','brown');

foreach($types as $type){
  ${$type} = $type;
}
```

Comment: OK.  But instead of hard-coding the array values in...can you represent those with the variable that contains the array?  That is why this is a bit confusing for me...every example I find in all the PHP Manuals...hardcodes this and that is not what I want to do...I have the values already in a variable...

The thing is someone above says that what I have is not an array but a scalar value...not sure exactly what that is or what I do with it to break it into its component parts.  Again, terribly sorry if I come off as really noobie-dumb here.  I hate asking for help.

Comment: If the data you are calling an array looks like this `"redgreenbluebrown"` then it's not an array, it's a string. There's no whitespace or anything to separate each component of the string, so you can't use `explode()` to create an array from it. If you don't know what your data looks like, print the variable to the page so you can see it, wrapped in a pre element. `echo '<pre>'; print_r($type); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: OK, this is the way the data looked at first.  I captured it in a module pref (yes this is LOTGD)

    </span><span class='colDkOrange'>shack<br /></span><span class='colDkOrange'>farmhouse<br />

So then I used a sanitize_html function on it to get to this

shackfarmhouse

so what would I now do to separate shack and farmhouse into two separate variables?

I had to first get rid of all the HTML stuff.  And I figured out on my own how to do it...but apparently I did not do it quite right, because if I got what I had wanted I probably should have got

shack, farmhouse